# Multiple comparisons for variance structure in R lme fit

Tags: r, mixed-model, variance, lme4-nlme

How can I compare variances for different levels of a factor in a mixed effect model?

I'm fitting a mixed effects model (in `R` using the `nlme` package) to signal onset time points, like so:

```
m1.lme <- lme(Onset ~ Signal, random=list(~1|Participant), data=mydata)
```

I suspect the variance of the onsets is different for various signals. So I add the `varIdent` argument to my fit:

```
m2.lme <- lme(Onset ~ Signal, random=list(~1|Participant), data=mydata, weights=varIdent(form=~1|Signal))
```

Now I want to compare the variances for different levels of the factor signal, i.e. is the variance for signal A significantly bigger than for signal B? Is this possible, and if so, how?